# Cannot get current location from the Google Map in Android app

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm making an Android app in which it is linked to the Google Maps, it does the same function as the Google Map, all the things in my app are working like getting a specified location you have typed but the problem is coming if I'm clicking on a circular mark which gives the current location it says:

> Google Map could not determine my precise location

How to get my current location? Can anyone help me with the code to get the previous location?

Comment: This is  the new way to ask help in SO. `please help in my code its urgent!!!  please help in my code its urgent!!! please help in my code its urgent!!!`

Answer (score 0):

You can see these [link1](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/) [link2](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-tracker-with-google-maps/). They have provided good tutorials.